# swiping issues in a tablayout which is inside a tab view of parent tablayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-support-design

I have added a Android support library TabLayout(Parent) with 4 tabs. I have added another TabLayout(Child) inside one of the tab views of parent tablayout. Swipe inside tabs of child tablayout is not happening correctly (Mostly due to conflict in swipe b/w parent and child tab layouts). **How can I disable swipe inside child tablayout?**

I have used separate viewpager for both the tablayouts.

Answer (score 0):

This Simple code can help you. Use this sample code in your parent fragment to add child tabs:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_index_markets, container, false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.markets_viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.markets_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    return view;
}
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()/*getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()*/);
    adapter.addFrag(new yourInnerFragment(), "tab1");
    adapter.addFrag(new yourSecondInnerFragment, "tab2");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
}
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Note that sometimes it is better to use `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getChildFragmentManager()`.
Also check this link: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180462